# Assist me to identify the exact conversion logic in this example

Tags: c#, hex, logic, ascii

I'm told that this is a hex data:
**5920CDB68401B5E3**

which is converted to ASCII and becomes:
**5920<=;68401;5>3**

No matter how i'm trying to figure out the conversion logic and achieve the same in code - i can't make it.

Can you please help me to identify how and by which concept that hex becomes that ASCII?

Comment: if you convert **5920<=;68401;5>3** to hex, you get **35:39:32:30:3c:3d:3b:36:38:34:30:31:3b:35:3e:33**, essentially your hex code strips out the front **3** in each hex and you will get your conversion **5920CDB68401B5E3**, try it in http://www.dolcevie.com/js/converter.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this conversion table:

```
0 : 0
1 : 1
...
9 : 9
A : :
B : ;
C : <
D : =
E : >
F : ?
```

Comment: wow, will do Eugen.
Which table is it?

Comment: It is the "look at the data" table ... Digits translate to digits, letters to special chars, with B->; occurring twice to confirm. A and F are a guess, coming from char sequence in the ASCII table